# column "parent_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist when creating SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

I am new in SQL and trying to understand Foreign key syntax. I know this was asked in multiple questions but each question I found did not seem to teach me what I am doing wrong here.
This is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
id int primary key,
name varchar(30),
age int,
gender bool
);

CREATE TABLE Minor
(
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Customer(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Adult
(
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Customer(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Shop
(
id int primary key
);

CREATE TABLE Drink
(
name varchar(30) primary key
);

CREATE TABLE AlcoholicDrink
(
FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES Drink(name)
);

CREATE TABLE NonAlcoholicDrink
(
FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES Drink(name)
);
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR:  column "parent_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
SQL state: 42703
```

Comment: Your tables don't have columns - a foreign key can only be declared on a column of the table.

Comment: https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/foreign-key-constraint.php

Comment: you need to add column parent_id first and then provide the reference to the base table

Comment: thanks for the clarification on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add fields in your tables to make the reference. Something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
id int primary key,
name varchar(30),
age int,
gender bool
);

CREATE TABLE Minor
(
minor_id serial primary key,
parent_id int,
other_fields text etc.
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Customer(id)
);
```

This is simply the reason why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
id int primary key,
name varchar(30),
age int,  
gender bool
);
CREATE TABLE Minor
(
parent_id int ,
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Customer(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an answer without just a code snippet:

You've got the right idea with `FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Customer(id)`. This bit adds a [*constraint*](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp) or a "rule" to your table. This constraint ensures that `parent_id` holds a real `id` in your `Customer` table.

The error message told us that `column "parent_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist`. The confusion comes, understandably, from mistaking the constraint declaration for a column declaration.

As others have pointed out, we need to both 10 declare the foreign key constraint and 2) declare the column.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
id int primary key,
name varchar(30),
age int,  
gender bool
);
CREATE TABLE Minor
(
parent_id int, -- Declare the column
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Customer(id) -- Declare the constraint
);
```